# Building my first mobile application

Tags: android, mobile, coronasdk, android-sdk-2.1

I`m thinking of making my first mobile application and I dont know where to start. so how do I starting building my mobile application?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

SO isn't a learning site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good places to start is [Getting Started](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/) and [Introduction to Corona](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/programming/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

- First download android studio from this link
- https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
- also download jdk from this link according to your machine specification and  - operating system
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
- install android studio according to instructions (it may take time as you need to download sdk etc)
- make sure jdk path has been set correctly in environment variables
  launch android studio and make new project (file>new>New Project now when gradle built is finished and no process is running)
- go to tools>android>avd manager
- create virtual device (choose one with low resolution)
- now download the latest android version (click next) select portrait click  -  - finish and close the window
- now click on run>run app (enable VTx in system bios if not enable)
- your hello world app will be launched emulator
- now come back to stack overflow mark this answer as correct
- Important- **now do as @Dwhitz told you and google such things before asking on stackoverflow**